# Move a commit to independent branch from master

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have branched off the wrong branch and I want to move a commit to the master instead of a feature branch. Tried with rebase master from feat2 but I'm getting "Current branch ... is up to date"

Basically I want to go from this

```
feat2                   F
                       /
feat1         C - D - E
             /
master A - B
```

To this

```
feat1         C - D - E
             /
master A - B 
             \
feat2         F
```

Of course F does not depend on any of C-D-E

EDIT: Forcing the rebase reveals that not only F is considered for it on feat2 but all of the commits from master are rebased (C-D-E-F). What I need is a way to tell rebase to "cut" at feat1.

Comment: I think rebase --onto and cherry-pick are basically your options here, and they are both potentially good choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `git rebase --onto`:

```
git checkout feat2
git rebase --onto E B
```

This says to rebase the commit `F` whose parent is `E` on top of commit `B`.  This leaves `feat2` looking as you want, with the `F` commit sitting directly on top of `B`.

Another simple way of handling this would be to branch a new feature 2 branch `feat2new` from `master`, then cherry-pick commit `F`.  After this, you can delete the old `feat2` branch and rename `feat2new` to `feat2`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feat2new
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 for commit F>
```

Now delete `feat2`, and do the rename:

```
git branch -d feat2
git branch -m feat2new feat2
```

Comment: Since I had only one commit I used cherry-pick but for more commits the --onto is definitely the proper way. It seems the proper command would be: git rebase --onto master feat1 feat2